# How do I sum the values in a column of a dataframe with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, sum

I have a large dataset with wind speed, temperature and pressure per hour over 1 period of 10 years. I want to calculate the average values of the wind speed, temperature and pressure per month over the entire 10 years. I have tried to calculate these averages but unfortanetely get stuck. Can anyone help me.

Example code:

```
# STN   YYYYMMDD       HH      FH       T       P
0   275 20110101    1   30  15  10217
1   275 20110101    2   30  18  10213
2   275 20110101    3   40  21  10210
3   275 20110101    4   40  20  10208
4   275 20110101    5   40  21  10203
5   275 20110101    6   40  22  10196
6   275 20110101    7   40  22  10196
7   275 20110101    8   40  25  10199
8   275 20110101    9   40  24  10198
9   275 20110101    10  40  32  10203
10  275 20110101    11  30  33  10200
11  275 20110101    12  30  40  10197
12  275 20110101    13  30  36  10197
13  275 20110101    14  30  38  10198
```

Comment: `df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['YYYYMMDD'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.to_period('M'), as_index=False).mean()`

Comment: Thank you @mozway. Would you also know how to add each month of e.g. january to get the average value for january over all those years. So, the average of the value of january in 2011, 2012, 2013, etc.

Comment: Yes, use `dt.month` in place of `dt.to_period('M')`